# React: how can I (dynamically?) generate pages from Data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I have:

```
A StockData.JS file with 50 different Stocks
--> A StockTile Component, that is populated with Data from the StockData file
 ---> A StockDetailPage Component also populated with Data from the StockData file
```

[image]

Both components, StockTile and StockDetail Page are entirely populated with data. Mapping them into an overview page delivers the desired result of getting 50 Tile components each filled with individual data.

As all of these 50 tiles should lead to 50 individual Detail pages, also populated with data:

How can I get React to automatically / dynamically generate 50 different StockDetailPages (each of them supposedly with an individual link?)*  I've understood mapping, filtering and props using React so far, but I'm completely clueless on how I could generate pages dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of react-router package:
([Completed sample Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-sample-z6qgu))

```js
//package.json

"react-router": "5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
```

And Create History

```js
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const history = createHistory();

export default history;
```

Define Routes

```js
import React, {
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useParams
} from "react-router";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import ProjectSingle from "./ProjectSingle";
import "./styles.css";

const history = createHistory();

const Footer = () => {
  return <div > Footer here. < /div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([{
      title: "Stock One",
      image: "/img/wp-logo.png",
      slug: "stock-one",
      key: 1
    },
    {
      title: "Stock Two",
      image: "/img/wp-logo.png",
      slug: "stock-two",
      key: 2
    }
  ]);

  /*const getProjects = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/projects')
    .then((res) =>{
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      setProjects(data);
    })
  }
  
    useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();
    AOS.init({disable: 'mobile'});
    },[]);
  */
  return ( <
    Router history = {
      history
    } >
    <
    div className = "App" > {
      projects.map((project) => {
        return ( <
          div key = {
            project.key
          } >
          <
          Link to = {
            `/project/${project.slug}`
          } > {
            project.title
          } < /Link> <
          /div>
        );
      })
    } <
    Switch > {
      projects.map((project) => ( <
          Route key = {
            project.key
          }
          exact path = "/project/:slug"
          render = {
            (props) => < ProjectSingle { ...props
            }
            project = {
              project
            }
            />} /
            >
          ))
      } <
      /Switch> <
      Footer / >
      <
      /div> <
      /Router>
    );
  }
```

Define the details component

```js
import React from "react";

import {
  Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useParams
} from "react-router";

const ProjectSingle = ({
  project
}) => {
  const {
    slug
  } = useParams();

  //TODO useEffect to get project details
  return ( <
    >
    <
    h1 > Details of {
      slug
    } < /h1> <
    div > {
      JSON.stringify(project)
    } < /div> <
    />
  );
};

export default ProjectSingle;
```